# Do files in /proc/PID directory have their own proc_dir_entry instance?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Do files in `/proc/PID` directory (including `/proc/PID` ) have their own `proc_dir_entry` instance?

As I known, each normal file in `/proc` including `/proc` has their `proc_dir_entry` instance.
(The instance address is stored in `proc_inode.pde`.)

After surfing the `procfs` source code in Linux 2.6.11, seems that the kernel doesn't create a corresponding `proc_dir_entry` instance for each `pid` directory in `/proc` and each file in `pid` directory.
Is this true?

If it's not true, which file in the kernel source code shows that the kernel create `proc_dir_entry` instance for `pid` directory in `/proc`.

Comment: Be more specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: > Do files in /proc/PID directory (including /proc/PID ) have their own proc_dir_entry instance?

Comment: No. proc_dir_entry is created for anything in /proc except /proc/$PID and what's below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, it looks like the pid entries are handled differently. See `fs/proc/base.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every process has its proc_dir_entry that is /proc/PID/task directory in common.